# Do any of the javascript techniques for detecting timezone/UTC Offset work when a laptop/smart phone crosses time zones?

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

If a person using either a laptop or smart phone travels across country into another timezone, are there any techniques that will automatically detect this. Or does the javascript just look at the timezone setting used when the person setup their laptop/smart phone.

Comment: They would all work, but in order for them to automatically update to reflect the new zone, the code would need to be re-executed (i.e. page reload).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript just reflects the environment where it is running, which just reflects the setting of the operating system.  Some operating systems will send an event notification, and some browsers will pick up on that to update automatically when the OS updates, but it's not a requirement at all.

It's also not a requirement that the OS updates its time when crossing a time zone.  Most devices allow you to set a time zone manually, and many people set the time that way.

Even if you use an OS feature to set the time zone automatically, that is either based on location or cell-tower data.  If the device cannot get such information (such as a phone in airplane mode), you won't get any update.

Either way, you would have to make an additional call to your JavaScript code to pick up on the change, or would have to use a timer to check it periodically.  There's no event that fires or anything like that.

So - maybe, sometimes, you can pick up on a time zone change - but certainly you cannot rely on it.